# bxtexlogo ruins \hologoFontSetup for some commands

Tags: logos

The `bxtexlogo` is nice, since, as  said in its documentation:

> The package `hologo` enables you to output many useful logos of popular
>   (and not so popular) TeX-family software. However its interface is a bit
>   cumbersome because you must type `\hologo{BibTeX}` instead of `\BibTeX`.
>   This package enables you to import some of logos provided by `hologo` as
>   simple commands, such as `\BibTeX`.

The problem is, it ruins some `hologo`'s setups:

- at least `\hologoFontSetup`,
- only for `\LaTeX`, `\LaTeXe` and `\TeX`,

as shown by the MCE below. Do you know what's going on?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\usepackage{hologo}
%
\usepackage{bxtexlogo}
%
\bxtexlogoimport{*}
%
\hologoFontSetup{general=\color{red}}
%
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\hologo{#1} \csname #1\endcsname}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \test{AmSLaTeX}
\item \test{AmSTeX}
\item \test{BibTeX}
\item \test{ConTeXt}
\item \test{eTeX}
\item \test{LaTeX}
\item \test{LaTeXe}
\item \test{LuaLaTeX}
\item \test{LuaTeX}
\item \test{LyX}
\item \test{METAFONT}
\item \test{METAPOST}
\item \test{pdfTeX}
\item \test{pdfLaTeX}
\item \test{TeX}
\item \test{XeLaTeX}
\item \test{XeTeX}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The documentation for `bxtexlogo` says “You cannot apply the management commands of hologo (`\hologoSetup` etc.) to the logos provided by this package.”

Comment: the three that are black are the ones that are defined in the format, so presumably the package doesn't define the `\foo` versions if `\foo` is already defined

Comment: @egreg Sigh... I missed it in the README displayed on my terminaL Anyway, strange it works in most cases.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed, should be the reason. Too bad anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you undefine the commands first it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%
\usepackage{hologo}
%
\usepackage{bxtexlogo}
%
\let\LaTeX\undefined
\let\LaTeXe\undefined
\let\TeX\undefined
\bxtexlogoimport{*}
%
\hologoFontSetup{general=\color{red}}
%
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\hologo{#1} \csname #1\endcsname}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \test{AmSLaTeX}
\item \test{AmSTeX}
\item \test{BibTeX}
\item \test{ConTeXt}
\item \test{eTeX}
\item \test{LaTeX}
\item \test{LaTeXe}
\item \test{LuaLaTeX}
\item \test{LuaTeX}
\item \test{LyX}
\item \test{METAFONT}
\item \test{METAPOST}
\item \test{pdfTeX}
\item \test{pdfLaTeX}
\item \test{TeX}
\item \test{XeLaTeX}
\item \test{XeTeX}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]